# How can I get Sikuli to interact with a VMware guest OS?

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

My problem is that I can't "type" (or send characters) inside of a text field.

VMware has this behavior that the first mouse click gets the focus on the main window and the second mouse click goes the the guest VM. It seems Sikuli loses the focus of the first click.

```
click('mywindow.png')
click('mywindow.png')
type('guest')
```

Is there a workaround to make Sikuli interact with a VMware guest OS?
When I configure VMware to accept a VNC connection I can interact with the via the VNC viewer, but that is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Suggestion: run Sikuli in the VMWare Guest, not on the VMWare Host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sikuli controls mouse and keyboard movements on the host OS.  As soon as you click on the guest VM, the mouse clicks are no longer registering with the host.  Sikuli is no longer in control of the keyboard and mouse and your script will fail.  @Raceyman is correct, you can run Sikuli inside your VM, but you cannot combine control of both host and guest.  VNC works because you are looking at screenshots natively on the host OS.  It is displaying "pictures" of the guest Os inside the native host VNC program.